# Problem generating pdfs with acts_as_flying_saucer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I'm using the rails plugin acts_as_flying_saucer to generate a pdf, but the pdf doesn't work:  i can save it ok, but when i try to open it i get this error message:

```
Unable to open document
File type SOR File (text/plain) is not supported
```

Here's my set up.  I'm using rails 2.3.4 and the latest version of the acts_as_flying_saucer plugin.  I have this route:

```
  map.all_help '/help/all.:format', :controller => "help", :action => "all"
```

which goes to this controller action:

```
class HelpController < ApplicationController
  acts_as_flying_saucer    

  def all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        render :action => "all", :layout => "help_pdf"
      }
      format.js
      format.pdf {
        render_pdf :template => 'help/all.html.erb', 
                   :layout => "help_pdf",
               :send_file => { :filename => "my-filename.pdf",  :type => "application/pdf"}      
      }
    end    
  end

end
```

and i also have this mime type defined:

```
 Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

When i go to the page, /help/all.pdf, it generates a 0 byte pdf (which i can save ok) and i get the error message from the top of this post when i try to open it.

Going to the standard web page version of the page (/help/all) works fine.  I thought maybe my java vm wasn't set up but it seems to be fine:

```
max-laptop:millionaire[subjects]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I'm out of ideas at this point...grateful for any advice! max

EDIT: Just noticed that a bunch of error output is in my mongrel-running tab:

```
ERROR:  'Premature end of file.'
Exception in thread "main" org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:191)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:71)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.getXMLResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:205)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.loadDocument(ITextRenderer.java:102)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:106)
    at Xhtml2Pdf.main(Xhtml2Pdf.java:19)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:719)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:189)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:636)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:707)
    ... 7 more
```

I'm wondering now if there's something wrong with the page i'm trying to convert to pdf.  I ran the html version of the page past the w3c validator and the page validates ok.    So now i'm stumped again...

EDIT 2: i think i'm getting closer now:  looking in my log, i see

```
Rendering help/all.html.erb
html file: /tmp/ff4c8ff01d544500ea4bfea43e6108c1.html
Sending X-Sendfile header /tmp/ff4c8ff01d544500ea4bfea43e6108c1.pdf
```

So, i'd expect /tmp/ff4c8ff01d544500ea4bfea43e6108c1.html to have the html version of my page in it, but it's just a four line empty text file.  No wonder flying saucer can't convert it.   I don't know why it's saving an empty html file though.

EDIT 3: here's the html i'm currently trying to convert

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <title>Help for Millionaire For Schools</title>
  </head>

  <body class="pdf">
        <div id="bgeffect"></div>        

    <div id="pageWrapper" class="mainHelpPages">

      <div id="helpContent">
        <div id="helpPane">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Welcome to my pdf</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div> 

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated XHTML of the page you're trying to convert to PDF?

Comment: Added in edit 3.  cheers

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you [solve this problem a year ago](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/192795) by setting `x_sendfile` to false?

Comment: Nicely googled john :)  Yes that worked then but isn't working now.  That was with a different app and a different system, and i can't seem to get it working this time around, whatever i set x_sendfile to.

Comment: The only other difference I can see is that your working version had `:disposition => 'inline'` - have you tried that?

Comment: yep, tried that.  I've tried every way i can think of of making it exactly the same as how i did it before (same layout, same doctype), to no avail.

Comment: Oh i did an edit to my original post with some errors from flying saucer btw.  cheers

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, it turned out to be really simple (and dumb).  The problem was this:  i was pointing to the layout i wanted to use in the normal railsy way,

```
:layout => "help_pdf",
```

But, it looks like you have to spell out the full file name: when i changed it to this, it worked:

```
:layout => "help_pdf.html.erb",
```

ARRRGGHHH!!!!!!  Ah well at least it's working now.  Thanks a lot John for having a look.

max